# multipart/form-data not working after upgrading xampp and php from 5.3 to 7.1

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, xampp

I am working on a project: codeigniter 3, xampp server 7, PHP 7. that was successfully posting post input type file and uploading data (at that time xampp 5.3, PHP 5). working was fine but now its not posting files. i have checked every configuration in php.ini, but still its not working. 
i have checked form multiple times

```
<form name="set_logo"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo basic_url('header/set_logo') ;?>">
     <div class="form-group form-group-material">
      <label class="display-block control-label has-margin">New Logo</label>
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image" class="form-control bg-teal-400" required />
      </div> <br/><button type="submit" class="btn bg-teal-400 btn-labeled btn-rounded btn-xlg" style="float:right"><b><i class=" icon-upload7"></i></b>Upload and Add Logo</button>
    </form>
```

here is my controller for accepting form data

```
public function set_logo(){ 
    if($this->session->has_userdata('is_logged_in') && $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') !== FALSE ){

    //  var_dump($this->input->post);die(); here this var_dump is showing NULL

        if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
            $image = $_FILES['image'];
                $id = '1';

            $uploaded_file_name = ($this->do_upload($_FILES, 'image') );
                var_dump($uploaded_file_name);die();
                      $data1 = array(
                         'img'=> $uploaded_file_name
                    );
                    if($uploaded_file_name!= '')
                    $this->header_model->set_logo($id, $data1);
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg', 'Logo successfully updated!');
                        redirect('header');
        }
        else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg', 'Unable to add Logo. Please Try again!');
        }
        redirect('header');
    }

    else{   
        redirect('home');
    }   
}
```

Comment: what is basic_url should be base_url in form action

Comment: `basic_url` ...  ***not working after upgrading xampp and php from 5.3 to 7.1*** seriously ??

Comment: In action, there should be `base_url()`. See this [manual](https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-url-helper/)

Comment: Edit question with your controller function. You can also use the codeigniter form helper http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html functions like form_open_multipart() http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#form_open_multipart

Comment: by changing basic_url() to base_url() it gives error object not found. my working is working properly with basic_url() in form

Comment: yes its not working after upgrading to 7. otherwise that's working fine in other system having php 5 and xampp 5

Comment: What does the generated output look like when you're using `basic_url()`? And what does _"not posting files"_ mean? Does the form get posted to the correct URL but without any data? Not posting at all? Error messages in the console/on the page? Have you dumped the `$_POST` and `$_FILES` arrays?

Comment: Have you named your filenames and classes correct where the first letter only is uppercase the rest lower case explained here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming It also could be some with htaccess

Comment: yes Mangus it posted data other than input type file field. i want to post image but couldn't. $files are set but not post giving any data

Comment: Why not use codeigniter file upload? http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: because have multiple image uploads according to roles, admin, sub-admin, users, slider, etc. 11 diff directories are being used instead of single directory.